# New iOS version simulator on older Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode14

I am having a problem with trying to get my Xcode project to run on my phone. Since I have a 2016 MacBook Pro I can't update Xcode to the latest version. And since it can't update to the latest version, I can't run my app on my phone. My phone is on iOS 17.2 and so I put the 17.2 simulator on Xcode but Xcode 14.2 can't run that new of a version. I am not in the Apple developer program because I am just learning and testing out the Swift language so I didn't want to pay for it yet. I was wondering if there is a way that I can get my app to run on my phone.

Comment: You might be able to patch macOS to run on your 2016 model. E.g. check out https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/MODELS.html But in general, Apple's stance on the matter is that you should throw away your perfectly good computer and pay them for a new shiny one.

Comment: I don't think you can run an app on a real device without a developer account, even if you had the latest xcode. But since you are "just learning and testing out", you can use playground and simulators available with whatever the version of xcode you have - that doesn't require developer account.

Comment: @SmartGamer wow, that’s awesome to hear! I’m glad you were able to be resourceful and fright back against this forced obsolescence!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue just use opencore legacy patcher to update your macos and then the xcode. However, ios 17 simulator may not work but you can run the build on your device. You don't need to buy the developer program to test your builds on your phone.
Note that if you are updating to sonoma then use latest patcher or else use 1.2.1 release, otherwise you will boot into recovery and need to reinstall the current copy of macos.

https://github.com/dortania/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/releases